# ionic2 Sending object data to Backand

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, drop-down-menu, ionic2

I created an ionic2 signup page. On the signup page, I created a drop down menu where the user can select their blood type. I am trying to send the selected blood type to Backand database. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong because the selected blood type is not showing up in Backand.

signup.ts

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import { BackandService } from '@backand/angular2-sdk'
import { LoginPage } from '../login/login';
import { AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
   templateUrl: 'signup.html',
   selector: 'page-signup',
})

 export class SignupPage {

  email:string = '';
  firstName:string = '';
  lastName:string = '';
  signUpPassword: string = '';
  confirmPassword: string = '';
  bloodType: Object = {};


  constructor(private backand: BackandService, private alertCtrl: 
  AlertController) {}


  public signUp() {

   this.backand.signup(this.firstName, this.lastName, this.email,this.signUpPassword, this.confirmPassword, this.bloodType)
  .then((res: any) =>
   {
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
    subTitle: 'Thank you for signing up.',
    buttons:['Login']
    });
    alert.present();
    this.email = this.signUpPassword = this.confirmPassword = this.firstName= this.lastName = this.bloodType = '';
    }
   );
  }
}
```

signup.html

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label>Select Your Blood Type</ion-label>
    <ion-select type="text" (input)="bloodType = $event.target.value" ng-model="bloodType">
      <ion-option>O Positive</ion-option>
      <ion-option> O Negative</ion-option>
      <ion-option> A Positive</ion-option>
      <ion-option> A Negative</ion-option>
      <ion-option> B Positive</ion-option>
      <ion-option> B Negative</ion-option>
      <ion-option> AB Positive</ion-option>
      <ion-option> AB Negative</ion-option>
      <ion-option> Unknown</ion-option>
    </ion-select>
 <ion-item>
```

Comment: that did not work. got an error.

Comment: error_handler.js:54 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): [object Object]

Comment: It seems you're having an issue with  `ion-select`.Please see the doc here. https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/select/Select/

Comment: yes I have looked at the documentation. thanks for helping!

Comment: Try printing whatever you are sending over to the backend first. Once u are able to get the value, then you then send them over. At ur backend side, print out all the values received. In this way, u are able to narrow down your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself. In signup.ts it should be ,

```
 this.backand.signup(this.firstName, this.lastName, this.email,this.signUpPassword, this.confirmPassword, {"bloodType": this.bloodType})
```

In signup.html it should be

```
<ion-select type="text" (input)="bloodType = $event.target.value" [(ng-model)]="bloodType">
```